# Delete special part from a list using Mathematica

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list like this:

```
{{-0.0019,1},{-0.0018,2},...,{0,11},{0.001,6},...}
```

I need to make a new list that start from zero value. like this:

```
{{0,11},{0.001,6},...}
```

How can I do?

Comment: try `Cases[{a_,_}/;>=0]@yourlist` or `Select[Positive@*First]@yourlist`

Comment: @kglr I receive this error: Syntax::: "{a_,_}/;" cannot be followed by ">=0".

Comment: @kglr Thank's. this Select[Positive@*First]@yourlist is true.

Comment: sorry, it should be `Cases[{a_,_}/;a>=0]@yourlist`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are probably 10 ways to do this.

```
lst = {{-0.0019, 1}, {-0.0018, 2}, {0, 11}, {0.001, 6}, {0.002, 6}}
lst[[  First@FirstPosition[lst, {0, _}] ;; -1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can also do

```
p = FirstPosition[lst, {0, _}]
lst[[Range[First@p, Length@lst]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update**

Actually `Cases` is not what you want. Since you want to start your new list only after the `{0,_}` entry in the old list.

> a new list that start from zero value

For example. given

```
lst = {{1, 10}, {-0.0019, 1}, {-0.0018, 2}, {0, 11}, {0.001,6}, {0.002, 6}}
Cases[lst, {x_, _} /; x >= 0]
```

Gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But you really want

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Same issue with `Select[Positive@*First]@yourlist`.

So I think using `FirstPosition` is what you want to use.

> And if I want new list with just before zero?

```
lst = {{1, 10}, {-0.0019, 1}, {-0.0018, 2}, {0, 11}, {0.001, 6}, {0.002, 6}}
p = First@FirstPosition[lst, {0, _}]
If[p > 1, lst[[1;;p-1]], {}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
lst = {{0,20},{1, 10}, {-0.0019, 1}, {-0.0018, 2}, {0, 11}, {0.001, 6}, {0.002, 6}}
p = First@FirstPosition[lst, {0, _}]
If[p > 1, lst[[1;;p-1]], {}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

ps. This assumes at least one `{0,_}` entry exists in the list. Otherwise, I would add a check for `NotFound` being returned from `FirstPosition` as well to make code more robust.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks.I don't care this point. And if I want new list with just before zero?

Comment: @caren I would still use `FirstPosition` but now count from 1 up to one less that that value. Updated.  Just need special case, for when `{0,_}` shows on first position.

Comment: Be negative or positive value it's not important. I want to separate  list from this position.

Answer (score 9):

#### [`Drop`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Drop.html) + [`LengthWhile`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LengthWhile.html)

```
Drop[#, LengthWhile[#, First @ # != 0 &]] & @ lst
```

> ```
> {{0, 11}, {0.001, 6}, {0.002, 6}}
> ```

#### [`NestWhile`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestWhile.html) + [`Rest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rest.html)

```
NestWhile[Rest, lst, #[[1, 1]] != 0 &]
```

> ```
> {{0, 11}, {0.001, 6}, {0.002, 6}}
> ```

#### [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html)

```
ReplaceAll[{___, a : {0, _}, b___} :> {a, b}]@lst
```

> ```
> {{0, 11}, {0.001, 6}, {0.002, 6}}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Another way, using `FirstCase` and `Position`:

```
lst = {{1, 10}, {-0.0019, 1}, {-0.0018, 2}, {0, 11}, {0.001, 6}, {0.002, 6}};

lst[[Det@Position[lst, FirstCase[lst, {0, _}]] ;;]]

(*{{0, 11}, {0.001, 6}, {0.002, 6}}*)
```

Or using `FirstPosition` and `TakeList`:

```
Last@TakeList[lst, {FirstPosition[lst, {0, _}][[1]] - 1, UpTo[Length[lst]]}]

(* (*{{0, 11}, {0.001, 6}, {0.002, 6}}*)*)
```

**Thanks for your excellent observation, Nasser!**

Comment: This does not really work. Same issue as with Cases., Try it on this `lst = {{1, 10}, {-0.0019, 1}, {-0.0018, 2}, {0, 11}, {0.001, 6}, {0.002, 6}};`  it should return `{{0, 11}, {0.001, 6}, {0.002, 6}}` but your solution returns `{{1, 10}, {0, 11}, {0.001, 6}, {0.002, 6}}` .

Comment: @Nasser Thanks, mate!

Comment: nice solution. Now it works.

Comment: I'm so grateful.

Answer (score 2):

Let `n` be the index of the original list of pairs `pairList` such that `newList = pairList[[n;;]]` is desired and for each element `elem` in `newList`, `First@elem` is non-negative.  Then the desired list is yielded by

```
pairList = {{1, 10}, {-0.0019, 1}, {-0.0018, 2}, {0, 11}, {0.001, 6}, {0.002, 6}};
SplitBy[pairList, NonNegative@*First] // Last
```

> {{0, 11}, {0.001, 6}, {0.002, 6}}

Comment: I want to separate the list from this position.